# How to fetch the custom label by using variable instead of label name

Tags: customlabel

Normally we fetched the label name by using label.labelname in apex code but i want to fetch the label name by using variable in apex code.Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method in your class.

```
public static String getLabelString(String labelName ){
    Component.Apex.OutputText output = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
    output.expressions.value = '{!$Label.' + labelName + '}';
    return String.valueOf(output.value);
}
```